# Usage of getting into his head

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

Can "Getting into his head" be used to suggest that someone is becoming crazy because of something? 
Example : The upcoming Physics exam is getting into Johns head

Comment: Not to be confused with 'gone to someone's head' which means they have become conceited.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression “[Get into someone's head](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+into+someone%27s+head)
(get into (one's) head)”  is used with the following meanings:

> 1. To begin to understand how one thinks.
>
>    - You need to get into the criminal's way in order to find a way to stop him.
> 2. To intentionally disrupt or undermine one's focus, confidence, or performance.
>
>    - The opposing coach called a time out at the last second to try to get into the kicker's head.

You are probably looking for the idiom:

[go to someone’s head](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/go-to-someones-head)

> to confuse, excite, or intoxicate someone.

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: On the contrary, the second sense in the first definition is the closest to *going crazy*. *That clown who plays the xylophone while skating is really **getting into Bob's head** [freaking him out].* To *go to someone's head* is used when somebody becomes overconfident or boastful—not when they're seeing pink elephants spraying graffiti on walls.